# How do I solve my Wordpress custom post-type anomaly?

Tags: wordpress, function, custom-post-type

My custom post-type is working well, I can create new post just fine and see the posts. but when I'm trying to access the post type url (/books/) I'm getting errors.

eg. I can access the actual post like
-- mydomain.com/books/lord-of-the-rings

I'm getting an error when:
-- mydomain.com/books/

When I access '**books**' (mydomain.com/books/), I think by default should list all my posts that been created in that certain post-type.

here's my functions.php

```
/* New Post-Type */

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_book' );

function create_posttype_book() {
    register_post_type( 'book',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'book' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Paper' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => true,
        )
    );
}

register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'book', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => __('book Category'), 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => false) ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error you are getting?

A couple of solutions:

- Permalink settings
- add 'has_archive' = > true, to your array
- check if archive.php exists in your theme folder (or create an archive-customposttypename.php file)

Comment: Thank so much. The bullet points really help me a lot to check the issue on by one. Permalink was already been set properly and I just have to check it again. I then added 'has_archive' = > true to my functions. I use a child theme so I just copy the archive.php from the parent and just rename it to archive-books.php. then everything work well. Thanks so much!